# Series, Calculating the limit , if does not exist prove it.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing, proof-explanation

$$ \frac{n}{n+2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{k+3}$$

I'm having a bit of difficulty trying to prove why the limit of this expression is infinity (well that what is my intuition says), may i have your help?

Comment: $$\frac{n}{n+2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{k+3} = \left(1+O(1/n)\right)\cdot \left(n+O(\log n)\right) = n+O(\log n) $$ or simply Cesaro-Stolz.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see why this expression approximates $n$? Hint: each fraction approximates $1$ for sufficiently large numerators.

Comment: By approximating by hand I saw where this sequence , goes that why i wrote that my intuition tells me this sequence tends to infinity

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{k}{k+3} \ge \frac12 \iff 2k \ge k+3 \iff k \ge 3$$

$$\frac{n}{n+2} \ge \frac12 \iff 2n \ge n+2 \iff n \ge 2$$

If $n \ge 3$,
$$\frac{n}{n+2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{k+3} \ge \frac{n}{n+2}\sum_{k=3}^n\frac{k}{k+3} \ge \frac12 \sum_{k=3}^n\frac12 = \frac{n-2}{4} \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} \infty.$$

Comment: I think i got the idea,
Also by proofing it with the epsilon-N definition, and the Infinite limits definition, How's that comes in the writing?
By choosing n>N , where N = 3?

Comment: @mathlooker To prove limit to infinity, one writes $M > 0$ instead of $\epsilon$.

Comment: I'll try writing a proof with your hint, i'll post it here

Comment: @mathlooker You don't even need one.  See the [definition of infinite limit](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/lHopital/define_limit.html).  At the last line, it's clear that $\dfrac{n}{4} \to \infty$ from definition.

Comment: Hmm, actually I think you're right, the requirements of question says i need to proof if the limit dose not exists, wait.. but the limit here tends to infinity and not to a specific L.
So I can just write the calculation and say the answer is infinity?

Comment: @mathlooker Yes, as the inequalities shows the desired conclusion

Comment: $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty }K_{n}=\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty } \frac{n}{n+2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{k+3}= \lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty }\frac{n^2}{n+2}\cdot\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{k+3}$$
$$b_{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{k+3}>0\\
a_{n}=\frac{n^2}{n+2} >0\\
\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty }a_{n}\cdot b_{n}=\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty }a_{n}\cdot \lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty }b_{n}
="\infty" \cdot 1 = \infty$$
How's that?

Comment: @mathlooker You can elaborate why $b_n \to$ constant, or simply $b_n \ge $ positive constant.

Comment: the explanation is about the limit of  the AM of the sequence inside of the sigma notation , and its limit is 1

Comment: @mathlooker OIC, though your claim can be justified by $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument.  I think that a lower bound approach is easier.